# Locked desktop in 23.10

Tags: 23.10

Today i was locked our from the desktop. I use Ubuntu 23.10 on a new Dell laptop. Mouse can be moved but nothing happen on clicks. Only solution was force shutdown with power button. It feels like a bug???
[image]

Comment: You may be running out of RAM and swap space. This can happen if you have too many applications and browser tabs open at the same time. By the way do not force shut down by holding the power button. Learn how to use REISUB to safely shutdown your computer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears for any Ubunty I worked: 18.04, 20.04, 22.04, 23.10 . And on different machines: PCs and Laptops. Seems like a bug. But noticed that from Ubuntu 22.04 I hit this bug far less frequently.